# No test found with Maven + JUnit + Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I'm triying to generate a .war with my Eclipse project and Maven. When I'm going to execute the task "mvn test" Maven don't execute/find any of my test:

```
C:\eclipseJava\workspace\myproject>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 is missing, no dependency informat
ion available
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocate
d to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myproject
---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 21 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ my
project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ myproject---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\eclipseJava\workspace\myproject\target\sure
fire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.424s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 19 11:47:53 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/10M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is part of my pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <name>myproject</name>

        <build>

    <!-- 
     <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
     -->
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>


            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                    <directory>src/es/mycompany/myproject/test</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>ValoresTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>


            <plugins>
            <!-- 
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>es/mycompany/myproject/test/ValoresTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    -->

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <warName>myproject</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/u</path>
                        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2</version>
            </dependency>

                ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            ...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>project-repo</id>
                <url>file://${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>maven-restlet</id>
                <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>utf-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        </properties>
    </project>
```

If I add the lines commented in **maven-surefire-plugin** I don't get the message but the tests don't run anyway...

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 is missing, no dependency informat
ion available
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocate
d to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myproject
---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 21 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ my
project ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproje
ct ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ myproject ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.190s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 19 12:01:22 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/10M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm a newbie in Maven and I don't know where is my fail :( Any help please? I'm working with Java, Eclipse, JUnit4 and Maven.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to configure this in your case but you might want to consider adapting your project to the [default Maven folder layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). It spares you a lot of extra configuration in your pom and avoids the problems you are having.

Comment: Did you make your test classes public?

Comment: My classes are public but my project is not adapted to the default Maven layout. So i'm going to work on it...

Comment: Try to comment out the <excludes> tags, because "<exclude>**/*.java</exclude>" seems to exclude all java-files, including your test.